# SolrNet and many to many relations

Tags: solr, solrnet

I haven't been able to find and example or documentation how you do a many to many relation in SolrNet, so I hoped one of you experts might have a clue or a link which can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no many-to-many relationship in Solr, and in fact there are no relationships at all. Solr's index is a flat structure. You must denormalize your data, this depends on what searches you will need. See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaDesign

Comment: Thanks, I just need to get my head around using Lucene is much different from database-design.